# Access Point and NodeJS frontend

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+

I have set up a wireless access point with my RPi 3 B+ as per the official instructions [on the RapberryPi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md), and that works well. I can connect to the internet via my RPi access point.

I would also like to integrate my home server as well onto the same RPi. I have followed [these instructions](https://thisdavej.com/beginners-guide-to-installing-node-js-on-a-raspberry-pi/) to install NodeJS, whilst also being able to access the RPi files through my Windows machine.

So far, I have both the access point and the server up and running, which is exactly what I wanted. I am able to connect to my access point, and I'm able to access the server from both the wireless client and on my ethernet LAN. However, the RPi seems to reboot (maybe?) shortly after I start my server.

Why is this happening? What steps can I do to diagnose this? Is what I'm trying to do even achievable?

**What I've done so far**:
For a couple of days, I've logged voltages every 10 seconds using `vcgencmd measure_volts`, and that stays constant at around `1.256 V`. I've also logged when the reboots happen, so that I can check the `journalctl` logs (not really sure what to look for TBH).

I'm so new to networking, I'm many levels below beginner, so please bear with me!

Thanks!

**Update**: Just thought I would also mention, the RPi gets really warm for what feels like not a lot of work. When I run `vcgencmd measure_temp`, I get `temp=54.2'C`, which seems excessively high. The voltage is still the same at `1.2563V`.